# Subtracting two rows based on created_at: condition in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, datetime

I currently have a graph that shows a cumulative total by day, but what I am really after is that day's marginal increase aka delta. How can this be done by query? Unfortunately, cumulative total is all that is available by API.

Here is my table:

```
org:          cumulative_donations_count:    created_at:
Goodwill      650                            2017-02-28 18:50:20.654996
Goodwill      300                            2017-02-27 18:50:20.654996
Goodwill      250                            2017-02-26 18:50:20.654996
Goodwill      100                            2017-02-25 18:50:20.654996
```

*Steps Taken* -- I started to iterate over a `self.where(org: goodwill).pluck(created_at:, donations_count:)` array by |date, value| in an attempt to compare the dates by their respective index value in the array, but our lead engineer wants it done purely by query. I also thought about adding a column to show the difference, but we want to run many different calculations on these values.

There is a base case of `if <= 1` for the number of records an org needs in order to be compared which should return nil. Obviously, the created_at: value will not be exactly 1 day behind in milliseconds.

Arguably, there are similar questions to this, but the conditions of this example are simple enough to be useful to many readers.

*UPDATE* -- expected output

`[[2017-02-28, 350],[2017-02-27, 50], [2017-02-26, 150], [2017-02-25, nil]]`

Comment: can you show the expected output as well?

Comment: thank you. updated to show the expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then you would use `lag()` in SQL:

```
select org, cumulative_donations_count, created_at,
       (cumulative_donations_count - 
        lag(cumulative_donations_count, 1, 0) over (partition by GoodWill order by created_at)
       ) as inc
from t;
```

This uses the [3-arg form](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) of `lag()`.  The second argument is the number of records to go back.  The third is the value for the first record (when there are no preceding records).

Comment: Thank you!  `lag(cumulative_donations_count, 1) over (partition by org_id ... where org_id = #{org_id};"` got this to work in a way that I could dynamically account for different id's and the base case

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are no null values in the count column, you can use `lag` to get the value on the previous row and subtract it from the current row's value to get the delta. For the first row of each group (ordered by created_at), the difference will be `null`. (You can use the default value of `0` if needed in `lag`)

```
select org,created_at,
cumulative_donations_count - lag(cumulative_donations_count) over(partition by org order by created_at) as delta_from_prev_day
from yourtable
```